# returning Abstract Types through REST

Tags: .net, wcf, xml-serialization

I am trying to build a rest service that will return some data that is a collection of an abstract class which contains various implementation classes.

How do i set up my REST return type to be able to specify the various types that will be returned.

for instance.

```
<RootType>
 <dataAttribute></dataAttribute>
<Array>
  <ItemofClassA></ItemOfClassA>
  <ItemofClassB></ItemOfClassB>
  <ItemofClassC></ItemOfClassC>
</Array>
</RootType>
```

I belive i Will need something like this in my definition.

```
class RootType{

[XMLType (Typeof(ClassA)]
[XMLType (Typeof(ClassB)]
[XMLType (Typeof(ClassC)]
public AbstractClass[] Array{get;set;}

}
```

Comment: Did you try this, and did it work? If it failed, how did it fail? In any case, why ask until you've tried it?

Comment: This is not a REST question it is an Xml Serialization question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe check [How can I use polymorphism in XML Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007626/in-net-xml-deserialization-how-can-i-allow-polymorphic-use-of-array-types/1009017#1009017) for a hint.