# Xml deserialization, perserving order across different tags

Tags: c#, .net, deserialization, xmlserializer

I have xml (which I have no control over) which I needwant to deserialize with the XmlSerializer. My trouble is that I need to preserve the order among two different tags in a single list. Let me give an example:

```
<users>
    <luser>..some more elements..</luser>
    <luser>..some more elements..</luser>
    <admin>..different elements than in luser</admin>
    <luser>..some more elements..</luser>
    <admin>..different elements than in luser</admin>
    <luser>..some more elements..</luser>
    <admin>..different elements than in luser</admin>
<users>
```

Now, if I deserialze this the straight forward way, I end up with two lists, one for lusers and one for admins. However, the order they appear in is the implicit ID! (Which of course should have been an attribute or element in the xml but alas it is not)

I've tried to make a meta element like this

```
[XmlElement("luser"),XmlElement("admin")]
public List<Person> Person { get; set; }
```

with

```
public class Person
{
    public Luser Luser { get; set; }
    public Admin Admin { get; set; }
}
```

where the plan was to check the list to see if the entry a luser or an admin, and have the people wrapper maintain the order of the elements. However multiple XmlElement attributes on a single property seems to be illegal.

Another acceptable solution would be to end up with two lists but where each entry in each list had an ID I could use to get the original order.

I want this to be as clean as possible. Searching through the xml afterwards to find the order, manually extracting the tags, and similar, is something I would avoid and do as a very last resort.

Comment: I know it doesn't really help you but it seems silly that you need to keep them in order. It clearly seems that there is no schema dictating this arrangement. Why can't you just have all lusers followed by all admins? Is this a constraint imposed by _your_ system, or is some other party demanding you don't alter the list? Also take a look at this, it may give you some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007626/in-net-xml-deserialization-how-can-i-allow-polymorphic-use-of-array-types

Comment: The first entry (user or admin) is id 1, the next is id 2 (regardless of it being a user or an admin) and so on. Yes it is silly, but there is nothing I can do about it. I'll look into the link, thanks

Comment: Ew, the userIds are based on the position in an XML document? That is horrible. I suppose it's out of the question to get it changed such that userId is an attribute?

Comment: I'm afraid the xml is set in stone and delivered to me from a third party. And yes I have cursed them quite frequently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which of course should have been an attribute...

Then make it an Attribute as soon as you can. Then work with the result.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(...);

var fixeruppers = doc
      .Descendants("users")
      .Elements()
      .ToList();   // isolate us from any movements in the doc

int id = 1; // base
foreach (var fixer in fixeruppers)
   fixer.SetAttributeValue("Id", id++);

XmlReader readerForDeserialize = doc.CreateReader();
```

Comment: +1. The reason the order is not preserved is that there is no order in XML like that - you want one, you have one. Whoever did that wrong is respnsoble - no way to fix that. Add an ID.

Comment: Thats' the cleanest way so far, while it feels a bit hacky it sure beats deserializing the whole ting manually or other things that have crossed my mind

Comment: Main point is to do it early, and cross your fingers. Most XML tools/parsers won't feel obliged to maintain any 'order'. Also note XDocument.CreateReader(), you can hook up most deserializers.

Comment: I accept this as the best answer, and a +1 for CreateReader, it made it less awkward to mix linq to xml and the serialzer.

Answer (score -2):

The following will dictate order (with the order:= value), it does not change how the class is serialized.

```
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
Imports System.ServiceModel

<DataContract()> _
Public Class MyClass

    <DataMember(order:=1)> _
    Public Property SomeData() As String

    <DataMember(order:=2)> _
    Public Property SomeOtherData() As String

End Class
```